Is there a compact set of sufficient and necessary criteria a function can have that guarantees that gradient descent finds *global* minima?
We obviously need the function in question to be differentiable for this notion to make sense.
Now, convexity is a sufficient condition. (strong) Quasi convexity is a weaker, but I think still sufficient condition.
But both of these are way too strong. There are very complex, highly non-convex functions when you consider higher dimensional spaces, where gradient descent nevertheless always converge for any initialization.
For example, a downwards sloped terrain, with a mountain on it. (anything will either roll past the mountain, or roll down the mountain and then down the terrain).

you don't even need convexity https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02030 (and btw, convergence and finding the global optima are not the same problem)

I know both of those thing. I said convexity is a sufficient condition. I also mentioned Quasi-Convexity, but from what I gather none of these, including (local) Quasi-convexity are necessary conditions.

Well example, you need to have a function that has a reachable minima...
